# Implementation of Integer'Value("X") in Ada

Tags: string, ada

I'm going to create a subprogram with two parameters; one string and one integer. The subrprogram is going to compare these two and see if they are the same.

For instance:

Type a string containing exactly 5 characters, and an Integer: **12345 123**

-- User types in bold

They are not the same!

```
with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;                                                                
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO; 
 
procedure Test2 is
    
    function String_Integer_Check(
        S : in String;
        I  : in Integer) return Boolean is         
    begin
        if Integer'Value(S) = I then
            return True;       
        else 
            return False;
        end if;  
    end String_Integer_Check;
           
    S : String(1..5);
    I : Integer;
   
begin
    Put("Type in a string containing exactly 5 characters, and an integer: ");
    Get(S);
    Get(I);
    Put("They are ");
   
    if String_Integer_Check(S, I) = False then
        Put("not ");
    end if;
   
    Put("the same.");  
end Test2;
```

My program works, *assuming* that the user types in a string of 5 characters. If the user doesn't my program won't work. How do I fix this?

If I type *123 1234* (String is 3 characters and the Integer is 4 numbers), I will get this error:

**They are**

**raised CONTRAINT_ERROR : bad input for 'Value: "123 1"**

Comment: Why do you want to compare a string with an integer? They are different types. The character '1' is not the same value as the integer 1. Have you tried reading the two values as integers? If you did this you will have no input problems and comparing the two values is very simple.

Comment: The task was to compare a string with an integer and to see if they are the same. By using Integer’Value(S) you can convert a string to an integer. The question still remains though, what about if a string is lesser than 5

Comment: They *did* type in a string of exactly 5 characters, just as you asked: `123 1`, followed by another string, `234`. Using a `.` to represent a space, what would you expect to happen if they typed `123..123`? or `.123.123`? What would _they_ expect to happen? Also, you just ask them to enter a string of exactly 5 _characters_; what about `!@£$%`? Perhaps you should specify 5 **digits**. And maybe check that the input conforms to your specification before calling `Integer’Value`.

Comment: Your function should just return `Integer'Value (S) = I` and your test should be `if not String_Integer_Check (S, I) then`.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the two inputs are on different lines. The I/O problems you are seeing result from mixing string I/O and integer I/O on the same input line. This is a problem when the string portion of the input contains more or less than 5 characters.

```
with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure value_compare is
   str_num : String (1 .. 80);
   length  : Natural;
   num     : Integer;
begin
   Put ("Enter a 5 digit number: ");
   Get_Line (Item => str_num, Last => length);
   if length = 5 then
      Put ("Enter a number: ");
      Get (num);
      if num = Integer'Value (str_num(1..Length)) then
         Put_Line ("The two values are equal.");
      else
         Put_Line ("The two values are not equal.");
      end if;
   else
      Put_Line
        ("The input value " & str_num (1 .. length) &
         " does not contain 5 exactly characters.");
   end if;
end value_compare;
```

Comment: This could use further explanation of _why/how_ this answers the OP's question.